# What is AWS iot security identity in AttachPolicyRequest?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I'm trying to add a certificate to AWSIot client in my AWS lambda function to activate bootstrap certificate. I follow to this code [justInTimeRegistration lambda.js](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-iot-examples/blob/master/justInTimeRegistration/deviceActivation.js):

```
AWSIot awsIotClient = AWSIotClientBuilder.defaultClient();
awsIotClient.createPolicy(new CreatePolicyRequest().withPolicyDocument(policy).withPolicyName(policyName));
awsIotClient.attachPolicy(new AttachPolicyRequest().withPolicyName(policyName).withTarget(???));
```

I don't understand what is 'target'. In the method description, I read :

target  - The [identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-security-identity.html) to which the policy is attached.

But the documentation from the link is unclear. In AttachPrincipalPolicy (deprecated) AttachPrincipalPolicyRequest with the principal, which is "a certificate ARN (as returned from the CreateCertificate operation)" - it is clear. But what is identity is unclear for me. Is it some entity like arn or it just some random value like certificateId? How I should specify target/identity to attach policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/attach-policy.html) from example, identity (target) is arn:

```
aws iot attach-policy \
--policy-name UpdateDeviceCertPolicy \
--target "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:123456789012:cert/4f0ba725787aa94d67d2fca420eca022242532e8b3c58e7465c7778b443fd65e"
```